# Acessando Webservice pelo Android - KSOAP2

Tags: java, android, web-service, android-eclipse

Eu estou criando um APP Android e tenho que me conectar com o web service da minha empresa para fazer o sistema de login, estou usando a lib KSOAP2 3.3.0.

O caminho do meu WS está por exemplo como: http://www.dominio.com/servicos/sambanet.asmx

O meu problema que acontece:

```
09-04 10:57:52.835: W/System.err(19717): 
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 
'Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction:
http://www.dominio.com/servicos/ObterIdentificadorLoja.'
faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@428e60d0
```

As variáveis armazenadas para a conexão:

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private final String URL = "http://www.dominio.com/servicos/ws.asmx";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/ObterIdentificadorLoja";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "ObterIdentificadorLoja";
private String TAG = "LOGAR";
```

meu WSDL é:

```
<wsdl:operation name="ObterIdentificadorLoja">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ObterIdentificadorLoja" style="document"/>
```

Source .Java completa:

```
package com.testes.infovendas;

//Imports
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

//KSOAP2 -- Lib de conexão Webservice SOAP
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

//Adicionais
import com.testes.infovendas.R;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InfoVendas extends ActionBarActivity {

//Variáveis
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private final String URL = "http://www.dominio.com.br/servicos/ws.asmx";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/ObterIdentificadorLoja";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "ObterIdentificadorLoja";
private String TAG = "ASSYNC";
private static String cnpj_cpf_codclie, codloja, seguranca, identificadorloja;
Button b;
TextView tv;
EditText et1,et2,et3,et4;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    //Identificando cada campo e função
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCodloja);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCPF);
    et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUser);
    et4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPass);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_informa);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnviar);
    //Listener para quando clicar no botão Enviar
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Se todos os campos forem preenchidos, será retomado o login
            if (et1.getText().length() != 0 && et1.getText().toString() != "" || 
                    et2.getText().length() != 0 && et2.getText().toString() != "" || 
                    et3.getText().length() != 0 && et3.getText().toString() != "" || 
                    et4.getText().length() != 0 && et4.getText().toString() != "") {

                //Pega todas as informações escritas nos campos e adiciona em suas respectivas variáveis para uso do WS
                codloja = et1.getText().toString();
                cnpj_cpf_codclie = et2.getText().toString();
                seguranca = "chavesecreta";

                AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                task.execute();

            } 
            //Se não for preenchido todos os campos, será retornado um TextView apenas informado para informar corretamente
            else {
                tv.setText("Por favor, insira todos os dados.");
            }
        }
    });
}

//Classe AsyncCallWS
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    //Retorna como null o valor do Identificador
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
        getIdentificador(cnpj_cpf_codclie, codloja, seguranca);
        return null;
    }

    //Mensagem e ação pós conclusão
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        tv.setText("identificador nº: " + identificadorloja + "  Conexão estabelecida. Realizando o login...");
    }

    //Mensagem ao clicar no botão Enviar
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
        tv.setText("Estabelecendo conexão ao servidor...");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
    }

}

//Classe para obter os dados do Identificador
public void getIdentificador(String cnpj_cpf_codclie, String codloja, String seguranca) {
    //Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    //Property which holds input parameters
    PropertyInfo identificadorPI = new PropertyInfo();
    //Set Name
    identificadorPI.setName("identificadorloja");
    //Set Value
    identificadorPI.setValue(identificadorloja);
    //Set dataType
    identificadorPI.setType(double.class);
    //Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty(identificadorPI);
    //Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    //Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    //Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        //Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        //Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        //Define identificadorloja como uma variável estática
        identificadorloja = response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Eu preciso acessar o "ObterIdentificadorLoja", só que sempre dá o erro de ou o "HEADER não foi possível ser reconhecido" ou "Timeout" ou "Referencia não foi setada para uma instância ou um objeto", e eu tentei de vários modos já..

Aonde eu posso estar errando?

Obs: Estou emulando nos meus próprios celulares (Moto X 4.4.4, Samsung Neo 4.1.3, Optimus One 2.3.3)

Comment: Teste, antes, todos os recursos do webservice aqui http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html

Comment: tudo funcionando normalmente, @IgorRonner! É um webservice que minha empresa já usa há tempos! E temos mais de 1000 clientes conectados nele utilizando as mesmas coisas que estou tentando..

Comment: onde você preenche a variável identificadorloja, eu não encontrei.

Comment: fica ao final do código: identificadorloja = response.toString();
  
  Ele atribui ao identificadorloja a resposta do webservice @IgorRonner

Comment: você está setando o valow identificadorloja no property sem ter ainda?

Comment: não @IgorRonner! No try ele está consumindo o webservice, e a resposta que ele entrega, ele atribui ao identificadorloja! Por exemplo, a resposta dele é 2 (int), ele atribui ao identificadorloja = "2", assim ele é mostrado na tela como teste que foi concluído.. No caso com este erro, aparece somente null pois não consegue se conectar..

Comment: mas isto não vem ao caso, o problema é ele não conseguir se conectar...

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após várias tentativas, eu mesmo acabei resolvendo o problema..

Segue a source do antes e depois:

Antes:

```
package com.testes.infovendas;

//Imports
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

//KSOAP2 -- Lib de conexão Webservice SOAP
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

//Adicionais
import com.testes.infovendas.R;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InfoVendas extends ActionBarActivity {

//Variáveis
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private final String URL = "http://www.dominio.com.br/servicos/ws.asmx";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/ObterIdentificadorLoja";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "ObterIdentificadorLoja";
private String TAG = "ASSYNC";
private static String cnpj_cpf_codclie, codloja, seguranca, identificadorloja;
Button b;
TextView tv;
EditText et1,et2,et3,et4;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
//Identificando cada campo e função
et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCodloja);
et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCPF);
et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUser);
et4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPass);
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_informa);
b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnviar);
//Listener para quando clicar no botão Enviar
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Se todos os campos forem preenchidos, será retomado o login
        if (et1.getText().length() != 0 && et1.getText().toString() != "" || 
                et2.getText().length() != 0 && et2.getText().toString() != "" || 
                et3.getText().length() != 0 && et3.getText().toString() != "" || 
                et4.getText().length() != 0 && et4.getText().toString() != "") {

            //Pega todas as informações escritas nos campos e adiciona em suas respectivas variáveis para uso do WS
            codloja = et1.getText().toString();
            cnpj_cpf_codclie = et2.getText().toString();
            seguranca = "chavesecreta";

            AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
            task.execute();

        } 
        //Se não for preenchido todos os campos, será retornado um TextView apenas informado para informar corretamente
        else {
            tv.setText("Por favor, insira todos os dados.");
        }
    }
});
}

//Classe AsyncCallWS
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

//Retorna como null o valor do Identificador
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
    getIdentificador(cnpj_cpf_codclie, codloja, seguranca);
    return null;
}

//Mensagem e ação pós conclusão
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
    tv.setText("identificador nº: " + identificadorloja + "  Conexão estabelecida. Realizando o login...");
}

//Mensagem ao clicar no botão Enviar
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
    tv.setText("Estabelecendo conexão ao servidor...");
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
}

}

//Classe para obter os dados do Identificador
public void getIdentificador(String cnpj_cpf_codclie, String codloja, String seguranca) {
//Create request
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
//Property which holds input parameters
PropertyInfo identificadorPI = new PropertyInfo();
//Set Name
identificadorPI.setName("identificadorloja");
//Set Value
identificadorPI.setValue(identificadorloja);
//Set dataType
identificadorPI.setType(double.class);
//Add the property to request object
request.addProperty(identificadorPI);
//Create envelope
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
//Set output SOAP object
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
//Create HTTP call object
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try {
    //Invoke web service
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    //Get the response
    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
    //Define identificadorloja como uma variável estática
    identificadorloja = response.toString();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

}
```

Depois:

```
//Variáveis
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/ObterIdentificadorLoja";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "ObterIdentificadorLoja";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://www.dominio.com.br/servicos/ws.asmx";
private PropertyInfo piCodLoja;
private PropertyInfo piCPF;
private PropertyInfo piSenha;
private String TAG = "ASSYNC";         
private static String cnpj_cpf_codclie, codloja, identificadorloja;
private static String seguranca = "SECRET";
//Classe para obter os dados do Identificador
public void getIdentificador(String cnpj_cpf_codclie, String codloja, String seguranca) {
    //Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    piCodLoja = new PropertyInfo();
    piCodLoja.setName("codloja");
    piCodLoja.setValue(et1.getText().toString());//get the string that is to be sent to the web service
    piCodLoja.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(piCodLoja);

    piCPF = new PropertyInfo();
    piCPF.setName("cnpj_cpf_codclie");
    piCPF.setValue(et2.getText().toString());//get the string that is to be sent to the web service
    piCPF.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(piCPF);

    piSenha = new PropertyInfo();
    piSenha.setName("seguranca");
    piSenha.setValue("Secret");//get the string that is to be sent to the web service
    piSenha.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(piSenha);
```